# Counting the average for many rows

Tags: sqlite, date, select, group-by, average

Each line is a second (timestamp increases by a second)
I want to calculate the average values for tel1 and tel2 for every minute.
Can you help?

```
CREATE TABLE "plik3" (
    "timestamp" REAL,
    "tel1"  REAL,
    "tel2"  REAL
);


1577833200.0    0.0         0.0
1577833201.0    0.0         0.0
1577833202.0    0.4000317   0.0
1577833203.0    0.80006206  0.80006146
1577833204.0    0.0         0.40002593
1577833205.0    0.400032    0.0
1577833206.0    0.800055    0.400024
1577833207.0    0.0         1.2000787
1577833208.0    0.40002337  0.8000576
1577833209.0    0.0         0.40002495
1577833210.0    0.0         0.0
1577833211.0    0.4000275   0.0
1577833212.0    0.400032    0.40003648
1577833213.0    0.0         1.2000787
1577833214.0    0.0         0.40003487
1577833215.0    0.8000595   0.0
1577833216.0    0.40002593  0.40003297
```

the base is large. 13,046,098 lines

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use arithmetics and aggregation for this:

```
select 
    cast(timestamp as int) / 60 * 60 timestamp_minute, 
    avg(tel1) avg_tel1, 
    avg(tel2) avg_tel2
from plik3
group by cast(timestamp as int) / 60 * 60
```

Expression `cast(timestamp as int) / 60 * 60` rounds the unix timestamp to the minute.

If you want to display the (rounded) timestamp as a datetime instead, you can use `datetime()` on top of this:

```
select 
    datetime(cast(timestamp as int) / 60 * 60, 'unixepoch') date_minute, 
    avg(tel1) avg_tel1, 
    avg(tel2) avg_tel2
from plik3
group by datetime(cast(timestamp as int) / 60 * 60, 'unixepoch')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this strategy.

- First use your starting timestamp as a constant: `1577833200.0`
- Create a subquery with the common minute where happen the action:

```
((1577833200.0 - 1577833200.0) /60) = 0
((1577833201.0 - 1577833200.0) /60) = 0
((1577833202.0 - 1577833200.0) /60) = 0
...
...
((1577833261.0 - 1577833200.0) /60) = 1
```

This calculation will output the same value for the concurrent records that happen in the same `minute`.

- Then you need to create another query grouped by the `minute` value

```
select minute, avg(tel1) as avg_tel1, avg(tel2) as avg_tel2 from
  (select ((`timestamp` - 1577833200.0) / 60) as minute, tel1, tel2 from plik3 as temp)
group by minute;
```